# Why can't a user with db_owner role version data?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog, versioning

I've made an enterprise geodatabase and added a user with db_owner permissions.

When I add a database connection in ArcCatalog and connect to this geodatabase using the user I created, I'm not able to version the data.

When I right click on a table or dataset in the enterprise geodatabase in ArcCatalog the menu is all grayed out except for the "Locks..." selection.

I've added the user to other enterprise geodatabases with the same permissions and everything worked fine. The user was able to version data.

What could be wrong here?

If I sign into the geodatabase that isn't working with the SDE login, I am able to version the data.

Comment: What data are you trying to Version?  Only the data owner should be able to version the data (ie if you loaded the data with SDE, then only SDE can version the data).

Comment: Really? So whatever user loads the data into the geodatabase. That user is the only one who can version the data? In this case I loaded the data logged in as SDE. I then created a new user in the geodatabase with db_owner permissions and they could not version the data. I figured if I made the user a db_owner they would be able to version it.

Comment: Is there any way around this? Also, is this in their documentation? I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: Ya, registering a dataset as versioned is not a trivial operation.  There are a number database objects that need to be created.  If you are interested in what is going on behind the scenes, you can read up on it at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_version/003n000000tq000000/.

Comment: There isn't a way around this that I know of.  You may want to look at your workflow and see why you are creating data as the SDE user in the first place.  Usually, you don't want to do that.  Also, why someone other than the data owner would need to be able to version a feature class.

Comment: You're definitely right and thanks a lot for your answer. I will just have to change the way I do things. I work for a small company and it just hasn't been a high priority to do it differently. Can you explain why it's a bad idea to use SDE? Also, if you would answer the question, I'll mark it as the answer since this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Creating data as the SDE user is kind of like creating data as the sys user in Oracle.  A few of the reasons I can think of right now:
 - security concerns (SDE has more permissions)
 - having a lot of IO on the SDE tablespace can effect performance
 - there is the risk of accidently corrupting metadata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the data owner is be able to version the data (ie if you loaded the data with SDE, then only SDE can version the data).  The reason for this is that when you register something as versioned, it is not a trivial operation.  Database objects need to be created.

More information about verioning is available in the Esri help doc [What is a version?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_version/003n000000tq000000/).